# Iterating over a large number of dataframe slices

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe summarising the budget I spent on some day, at every hour of the day (2 columns `Hour of day` and `Cost`).

I have to group consecutive hours of the day into 6 groups, for example: 0 to 3, then 4 to 10, 11 to 15, 16 to 18, 19 to 21, 22 to 23, which can also be noted as a tuple: (4, 11, 16, 19, 22).

Then, for every of these slices, I want to do some basic operations. The end goal is to extract the combination that achieved the lowest sum of variances of `Cost` across all time ranges. (in other words, which combination managed to best group similar hours of the day together).

I tried for a given day, to iterate over all possible combinations of 5-length tuples of numbers ranging from 1 to 23 with itertools.combinations. But the main problem is when I'm trying to do some basic operation on each of the slice. It is taking already 35 seconds to extract a single time-range (eg. 0 to 3).

With `day` being my dataframe of 2 columns (`Hour of day` and `Cost`) and 24 rows, this is what I have so far for the slicing part:

```
import itertools

for item in itertools.combinations(range(1,24), 5):
    day_slice_1 = day.loc[(day['Hour of day'] < item[0])].copy()
    day_slice_2 = day.loc[(day['Hour of day'] >= item[0]) & (day['Hour of day'] < item[1])].copy()
    day_slice_3 = day.loc[(day['Hour of day'] >= item[1]) & (day['Hour of day'] < item[2])].copy()
    day_slice_4 = day.loc[(day['Hour of day'] >= item[2]) & (day['Hour of day'] < item[3])].copy()
    day_slice_5 = day.loc[(day['Hour of day'] >= item[3]) & (day['Hour of day'] < item[4])].copy()
    day_slice_6 = day.loc[(day['Hour of day'] >= item[4])].copy()
```

This filtering takes a lot of time when repeated 33649 times. Can you think of any way to achieve this faster?

Comment: `combination` is not being used inside the loop. I fail to understand what its purpose is.

Comment: sorry that's a typo, please read `item`, not `combination`